# How to Autofill dynamic column in VBA?

Tags: vba

I have column K with a bunch of dates and I want to get the number of days between K's date and today's date inserted in column O.

My  code for the first row is:

```
 Range("O2").Value = Date - Range("K2").Value
```

How can I repeat this code for the rest of the column? Also, keep in mind that the length of populated cells in column K is dynamic and always changing.

Thanks to all that can help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before:

[image]

```
Sub Main()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("O" & i) = DateDiff("d", Now, Range("K" & i))
    Next i
End Sub
```

after:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Range("O2").AutoFill Range("O2:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row)
```

That is if you have the formula already in cell O2.